# Comparing a gene to the reference sequence at the single position

Tags: python, list, comparison, genetics

I have a homework problem where I retrieved data from a fasta file. Now, I need to check the "slim" position to see if the base is a SNP (for example, reference is a T, but the alternate is A. How do I locate the base in the reference sequence for comparison?

I tried running a For loop, but I have no idea if it is actually running through the sequences.

```
lymphoma = []
lymphoma_variants = []
outfileLymphoma = open("lymphoma_variants.txt", 'w')
print('IndividualID', 'variantID', 'GeneDiseaseInfo', sep = '\t', file = outfileLymphoma)
#want to compare the Non-h Lymphoma variants

for position in range(len(seqlist)):

    if position == 246708:
        if reference == 'G':

            lymphoma.append(lymphoma_variants[0:])
            print(name, rsid, geneinfo, sep = '\t', file = outfileLymphoma)
        else:
            continue
    else:
        continue

    if position == 248722:
        if reference == 'A':

            lymphoma.append(lymphoma_variants[0:])
            print(name, rsid, geneinfo, sep = '\t', file = outfileLymphoma)
        else:
            continue
    else:
        continue
```

The code will ideally check each individuals sequence and if there is a SNP for lymphoma, it will output into a file. The only thing that outputs are the headers and a random individual's data. Thank you, for your advice!